# Versioning your files to avoid browser cache in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, versioning, browser-cache

I read the no cache solution and this one on the web here: https://sebhastian.com/javascript-versioning/ where to fix this problem, you needed to add versioning to your `util.js` file request on the `<script>` tag. The easiest way would be by adding a query string parameter `v` as follows:

```html
<script src="util.js?v=1"></script>
```

This is all gravy but we need to be able to automate the versioning similar to the solution they suggest with Webpack.

In the following webpack.config.js file, the name of the JS file generated by Webpack follows the `[name].[contenthash].js` pattern. The `contenthash` will be replaced by a unique hash based on the content of the file.

Anyone with idea how to achieve the same with PhpStorm?

Comment: Not sure what you expect from the IDE here. Unlike webpack, it doesn't generate any files for you

Comment: I assume there isn't a plugin that can handle the functionality of webpack to autogenerate the file changes with their respective versioning.